# How to make background transparent while bootstrap loader

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to make a bootstrap loading image while API returns a result. How can I make the background transparent?

Here is the HTML markup and the CSS:

```html
<div class="loader" ng-hide="data.length > 0"></div>


<style>
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #D4D4D4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
    position: fixed;
    top:100px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 99999999;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Add `background-color: transparent` to `.loader`

Comment: I mean background color for all the page .. with loader

Answer (score 0):

Add background-color: transparent to .loader

```html
<div class="loader" ng-hide="data.length > 0"></div>


<style>
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #D4D4D4;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 120px;
    position: fixed;
    top:100px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 99999999;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I mean background color for all the page .. with loader

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a div of smaller size over the page with the loader and make it a light gray and put the opacity lower like:

```css
#div1{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background-image: url("https://images3.alphacoders.com/823/82317.jpg");
}

#div2{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:gray;
  opacity:.7;
  position:absolute;
  top:150px;
  left:150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div> 
</div>
```

You can then place the loader inside that smaller div and have that div appear when the API is fetching the data.